# Trying to run Flask on localhost, refused to connect

Tags: flask, localhost, virtualenv

I'm trying to run my Flask application on 127.0.0.1:4141 but all I've been getting is this which essentially is the localhost refused to connect, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED & vice versa.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VT1f.png)

I was running my application on PuTTY. If I run it on Flask on my local cmd prompt, it works for some reason.

I'm just wondering whether there's anything I can do to get it working.

Comment: i see you are using `https`. Make it `http`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reach the url from the same machine? if not try to change the ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0